# NiFi: unable to find valid certification path to requested target is thrown

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

My flow runs well with public servers, but if I want to use an internal server *https://(internal-server-name)* for testing I get a

```
2023-08-17 16:13:43,686 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] d.f.i.n.s.processor.SherlockProcessor SherlockProcessor[id=19991ee9-1fd5-1f3e-cead-aa7ffde2dfad] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target is thrown
```

I know I have to add the certificate of this server to the Java 11 keystore

**nifi.properties**

```
nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.p12
nifi.security.keystoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
nifi.security.keyPasswd=de64e15719fc0162ec9e600b417a5101
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.p12
nifi.security.truststoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I saved the certificate under *c:\temp\fct-intern.crt* and run the following admin command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore "C:\xampp\nifi-1.19.0\conf\keystore.p12" -storetype PKCS12 -storepass xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -noprompt -alias Root -file "c:\temp\fct-intern.crt"
```

the result of this call is

```
Certificate was added to keystore
```

I generate the StandardRestrictedSSLContextService with the same parameter and enabled it (validation was successful)
[image]

rebooted the server but still gets the error

Can someone see my error?

Frank

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: Are you sure that you have also placed the certificate on the right path as specified on the `nifi.properties`

Answer (score 0):

@Frank

You need to create an [SSL Context Service](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ssl-context-service-nar/1.21.0/org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardSSLContextService/index.html) referencing a new keystore and truststore that includes your self signed cert.  There are plenty of docs and such around this here in stack or out on open web  The other keystore and truststore is for nifi itself.

Comment: yes, I created the SSL Context Service the same. (I added the screenshot above)

Comment: I use separate keystores and jks to solve external https connections,  so im unsure of the behavior using the main keystores for nifi and in PK format.       Here is a post that shows how i do it..  https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Configure-StandardSSLContextService-for-Elasticsearch/m-p/302719